# Problem connecting to mySQL database using xamarin Andriod only but works in iOS and UWP

Tags: mysql, xamarin

I am connecting to mySQL server directly(Learning purposes only) from Xamarin cross platform App.
The connection is working good in both iOS and UWP but in android it throws an error in this line:
await conn.OpenAsync();

This is the full error:

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor (System.String exePath, System.Boolean includeUserConfig) [0x00050] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths (System.String exePath, System.Boolean includeUserConfig) [0x00018] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths () [0x0000a] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName (System.String configPath) [0x0006d] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp () [0x00000] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.get_IsAppConfigHttp () [0x00006] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor () [0x00051] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem () [0x00024] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem () [0x00060] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem () [0x0000a] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x0000a] in <0e721f564ffa49e6b1d97ad7b9fda1f2>:0   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor () [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor () [0x0001e] in :0 }

Hope someone can help me with this error
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+mysql+ReplicationManager+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using MySql.Data package and obviously it doesn't support Android yet

The solution is: use MySqlConnector package.

Side note: MySqlConnector package didn't work with: await conn.openAsync();
I had to use: conn.open();

It worked for iOS, Android, and UWP.